# Using variable in awk output

Tags: awk

The following works as expected.

```
awk -F'^' '{printf "set %s:%s %s\n",$1,$2, $7}' todel.txt | sed 's/$/\\r\\n/' >> tofile.txt
```

But when I try to add a variable to output as shown below, I get an error:

```
awk -F'^' '{printf "set %s:%s:%s %s\n",$1,$2,$myvar $7}' todel.txt | sed 's/$/\\r\\n/' >> tofile.txt
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$myvar` doesn't expand in single quote.
You can use the `-v` option to pass shell variable to `awk`:

```
awk -F'^' -v myvar=$myvar '{printf "set %s:%s:%s %s\n",$1,$2,myvar,$7}' todel.txt
```

Comment: awk: (FILENAME=todel.txt FNR=1) fatal: not enough arguments to satisfy format string # does not seem to work as expected.

Comment: I added the missing comma. I'm not at my computer so cannot test. )-:

Comment: Yes, I haven't test the missing comma too.

Comment: +1 Best to use quotes for the -v argument to protect whitespace `awk -v "myvar=$myvar" ...`